# SoundEffectInstance and progress bar

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my WP application I'm playing a lengthy sound effect and i am trying to 
update progressBar with song state, but I just can't find a way, any help would 
be appreciated.

My sound is standard  `SoundEffectInstance sound;`

and:

```
if (sound.State == SoundState.Paused)
                {
                    sound.Resume();
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sound.Stop();
                    }
                    catch { }
                    Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sounds.wav");
                    var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
                    sound = effect.CreateInstance();
                    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                    sound.Play();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any way to get the length of the sound, either in bytes or units of time, you can use that value. Just compare the number of bytes streamed or the amount of time elapsed (depending on which you can get) to the total, and set the loading bar accordingly.